# HTML scrolling issue in dialogs on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, ember.js

I'm developing a web application based on EmberJS, that should be running on multiple device types. The application includes dialogs, that are handled using the `ember-modal-dialog` and `liquid-wormhole` addons.

When opening the dialog on an iPhone, scrolling within the dialog eventually stops working, and instead of scrolling the content, some underlaying(?) elements are overlapping the dialogs content from the top or bottom (depending on the scroll direction). It's actually hard to explain, so I've made a video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Xfvxvx89r91svEyybMf1j6HFD3v_Tkl/view

Also, you can try it yourself. Click on the following link, and then on the button of the first item on the page.

https://rkr9z8g.suitepad.io/category/6463/page/22280

Does anyone knows or have an idea, how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've got same problem in my project. But i found that some duplicate style on my div. Try remove `overflow-y: scroll` and add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`. Hope that helps.

Comment: I found your problem. Multiple `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` on  `three` selectors. Remove it from `body, html`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changing the use of `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` removed the visual glitches, where parts of other elements where overlapping. Unfortunately, you still get into the state, where it's impossible to scroll. I've updated the app, you could use the link above and check. Any other ideas for improvements?

Comment: Glad to hear. Unfortunately i have no idea :) sorry for that. Wish you best goodluck :)